# Using PHP CURL to get a website through a proxy, how can I know exactly what is being sent through fiddler?

Tags: php, curl, fiddler, fsockopen

I am using CURL along with a proxy provider to get data from certain website, 
but when I try to make a request fiddler displays information only from the file using CURL and not from the proxy IP that actually makes the main request and brings the data.

How can I do to display what is being sent/received from the proxy request (proxy IP) in fiddler monitor? can I use fsockopen instead?

NOTE: As you may know a proxy is a mediator between the client and the server, in this case I am using CURL to retrieve information using a proxy provider as mentioned before, what I want to display in the Fiddler monitor is the request among the proxy and the requested website and not through the file using CURL which is already displayed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need access to the proxy server. e.g. given

```
you -> proxy -> site_you_want
```

you only have access to the `you -> proxy` connection, and cannot see what's happening on the `proxy -> site_you_want` link. That's a whole different machine and tcp connection, which you cannot access from where you're sitting.

Comment: So, if everything ends when the request is made through the proxy why the proxy IP is not displayed in fiddler? I mean, it's like if you access google.com and you can see the host in the monitor, why not with the IP.

Comment: there's 2 tcp connections involved. you->proxy, and proxy->site. anything you do on the "you" side can only see you->proxy. the proxy->site stuff is completely out of reach.